# Azure IoT Edge OPC Publisher message encoding

Tags: azure-iot-hub, opc-ua, opc, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I want to send telemetry data from Azure iot edge device to IoTHub through OPC publisher module.

OPC publisher can be configured to encode the message either Json ("--me=Json") or Uadp ("--me=Uadp") before sending.
[OPC Publisher parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIZT3.png)

https://github.com/Azure/Industrial-IoT/blob/main/docs/modules/publisher-commandline.md

So I configured my edge device to send the message in uadp message encoding format as its compact and compressed , However When I monitor the message received to IoTHub, its unreadable.

[Message monitoring in IoTHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2qia.png)

Any one can help how we can decode the uadp message to readable format in IoTHub so I can process it in Azure stream analytics

Comment: You would need a UADP decoder, but as far as I know, such is not available on the Azure side. So, better to use JSON, after all.

Comment: Thank you @JouniAro
I am wondering why I have the encoding capability in OPC publisher, However  I am not able to decode the message in the cloud.